# WCF consume by dotnet winfom client and config entry

Tags: wcf

i am new in WCF but i am bit familiar with web service (ASMX file)

### i have couple of question on wcf client config entry

when we create any web service (ASMX) proxy then nothing add in config file like below entry but in case of WCF the below entry adds. i just need to know the significant of the below entry.

1) if i delete these below entry then what will happen....can't i call the service from the client side?

2) just tell me when we call web service from client side then how do i say that which endpoint address my service will use to call service if there are more than one endpoint address added in client side ?

3) how do i explicitly mention web service url from cient side when i will make a service call?

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:00:05"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/CommService/"
            binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService"
            contract="Services.ICommService" name="WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes these are important configuration that are required by WCF. Either you provide it through config file or your code.

1) You need to provide it some where. If you take them fro config . You should be doing it in code.

2) WCF has basic rule of ABC . Address , Binding and Contract.  Again you don't have to say anything if its already in your config file.

For multiple clients . You can also mention the endpoint name from your config file. ForExample

```
MyClient someClientObject = new MyClient("WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService");
```

3) By default, when you Add Service Reference operation,  WCF Runtime gets you a client side proxy .

You can do it like this in a simple way. ParameterLess.

MySVCClient svcproxy = new MySVCClient ();

You need to have   entry with your service contract .
You can also use as follows with constructor ... using endpoint Adddress and Bidning etc.

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding= new BasicHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None);   
EndpointAddress endpointAdd= new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/CommService/");
MySVCClient svcproxy = new MySVCClient (myBinding, endpointAdd);
```

Since you are defining everything in code here. You don't need anything in config file.

Comment: if i instantiate proxy class the way u said like MyClient someClientObject = new MyClient("WSDualHttpBinding_ICommService"); does it work. MyClient ctor parameter take no param then how can i pass the endpoint name.

Comment: When you define an endpoint in config . You name it . If you look closely in your configuration file. There is endpoint name that i used in my sample above.  Other wise you have to instantiate the way i mentioned in last sample which doesn't require any configuration.